# Getting index of currently executing input in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    with Pool(processes=5) as p:
        p.starmap(name_of_function, all_inputs)
```

I have a piece of code like above that executes a function in parallel. Assuming that `all_inputs` has 10,000 elements, I would like to know which one is currently executing e.g. 100 out of 10,000... Is there a way to get that index?

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: @georgexsh, no linux

Comment: Since starmap is synchronous - from where do you want to be able to find this out?

Comment: Do you want to know which item is currently being processed (e.g. now working on number 100 out of 10,000), or which process is calculating a particular item (e.g. item 100 is being calculated by process 3)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The worker process within `multiprocessing.Pool` is an instance of `Process`, it keeps [an internal counter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L74-L75) to identify itself, you could use this counter along with [OS process id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier):

```
import os
from multiprocessing import current_process, Pool


def x(a):
    p = current_process()
    print('process counter:', p._identity[0], 'pid:', os.getpid())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(2) as p:
        r = p.map(x, range(4))
    p.join()
```

yields:

```
process counter: 1 pid: 29443
process counter: 2 pid: 29444
process counter: 2 pid: 29444
process counter: 1 pid: 29443
```

Comment: This looks like it's an ID for the worker, but not a count of how many items have been processed.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp yes it is a process id, why you think it is the counter of items?

Comment: because that is what the original question seems to be asking for.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp well, that is fair, but op disappeared without any further feedback.

Answer (score 8):

IIUC, you can pass in the indexes as well. (Steal the setup from @user1767754) (Please let me know if this is not what you are looking for.)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr_with_idx = zip(arr, range(len(arr)))

def x(a, idx):
    print(idx)
    return a*a

with Pool(5) as p:
    p.starmap(x, arr_with_idx)
```

Or more concisely, use `enumerate`

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

def x(idx, a):  # different here
    print(idx)
    return a*a

with Pool(5) as p:
    p.starmap(x, enumerate(arr))
```

[`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) will unpack each tuple and you can print out the index part.

Comment: @user308827 comments so that I can improve?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `current_process` method from multiprocessing. If this isn't accurate enough, you could even pass the processes a `name` using a `uuid`

```
from multiprocessing import current_process


def x(a):
    print(current_process(), a)
    return a*a

with Pool(5) as p:
    p.map(x, [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: `  An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...
        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest passing the index along with the other arguments. You could use `enumerate` perhaps combined with a generator expression add the value to your existing arguments. Here's code that assumes `all_inputs` is an iterable of tuples:

```
with Pool(processes=5) as p:
    p.starmap(name_of_function, ((i,) + args for i, args in enumerate(all_inputs)))
```

You can choose from a bunch of variations on this general theme. For instance, you could put the index at the end of the arguments, rather than at the start (just swap `(i,) + args` to `args + (i,)`).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to discover which process is handling value 100 is to **divide the array in equal parts before the Pool starts**. This lets you control which processes in the Pool handles what part of the array (since you are passing predefined *start,end* indexes for each of them to work on).

For instance, if `all_inputs` had 50 elements with values ranging from 80 to 130, a simple job division for an 8-core CPU would return the following pairs of indexes:

```
Process #0 will work on indexes [0:5] with values: 80 - 85
Process #1 will work on indexes [6:11] with values: 86 - 91
Process #2 will work on indexes [12:17] with values: 92 - 97
Process #3 will work on indexes [18:23] with values: 98 - 103
Process #4 will work on indexes [24:29] with values: 104 - 109
Process #5 will work on indexes [30:35] with values: 110 - 115
Process #6 will work on indexes [36:41] with values: 116 - 121
Process #7 will work on indexes [42:50] with values: 122 - 130
```

When the Pool starts, you already know which one is going to be responsible for processing value 100.

The success of this approach relies on `jobDiv()` to do it's magic and divide the data for the processes, based on the size of the input array and the number of available CPU cores.

**Source code**:

```
import multiprocessing as mp    

# processArray(): a parallel function that process an array based on start and 
#   end index positions.
def processArray(procId, array, indexes):
    startIdx, endIdx = indexes
    print("  Process #" + str(procId) + " startIdx=" + str(startIdx), " endIdx=" + str(endIdx))

    # Do some work:
    for i in range(startIdx, endIdx+1):
        print("    Process #" + str(procId) + " is computing index " + str(i), " with value " + str(array[i]))


# jobDiv(): performs a simple job division between available CPU cores
def jobDiv(inputArray, numCPUs):
    jobs = []
    arrayLength = len(inputArray)

    jobRange = int(arrayLength / numCPUs)
    extra = arrayLength - (jobRange * numCPUs)

    prevEnd = 0
    for c in range(numCPUs):
        endIdx = (c * jobRange) + jobRange - 1
        if (c == (numCPUs-1)):
            endIdx += extra

        startIdx = prevEnd
        if ( (c > 0) and (startIdx+1 < arrayLength) ):
            startIdx += 1

        jobs.append( (startIdx, endIdx) )
        prevEnd = endIdx

    return jobs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize dataset for multiprocessing with 50 numbers, with values from 80 to 131
    nums = range(80, 131)

    # How many CPU cores can be used for this dataset
    numCPUs = mp.cpu_count()
    if (numCPUs > len(nums)):
        numCPUs = len(nums)

    # This function returns a list of tuples containing array indexes for
    # each process to work on. When nums has 100 elements and numCPUs is 8,
    # it returns the following list:
    #   (0, 11), (12, 23), (24, 35), (36, 47), (48, 59), (60, 71), (72, 83), (84, 99)
    indexes = jobDiv(nums, numCPUs)

    # Prepare parameters for every process in the pool, where each process gets one tuple of:
    #   (cpu_id, array, array_indexes)
    jobArgs = []
    for id, arg in enumerate(indexes):
        start, end = arg
        print("Process #" + str(id) + " will work on indexes [" + str(start) + ":" + str(end) +
              "] with values: " + str(nums[start]) + " - " + str(nums[end]))
        jobArgs.append( (id, nums, arg) )

    print("* Starting Pool")

    # For every process, send the data for processing along with it's respective tuple of parameters
    with mp.Pool(processes=numCPUs) as p:
        sums = p.starmap(processArray, jobArgs)

    print("* Finished")
```

**Output**:

```
* Starting Pool
  Process #0 startIdx=0  endIdx=5
    Process #0 is computing index 0  with value 80
    Process #0 is computing index 1  with value 81
    Process #0 is computing index 2  with value 82
    Process #0 is computing index 3  with value 83
    Process #0 is computing index 4  with value 84
    Process #0 is computing index 5  with value 85
  Process #1 startIdx=6  endIdx=11
    Process #1 is computing index 6  with value 86
    Process #1 is computing index 7  with value 87
    Process #1 is computing index 8  with value 88
    Process #1 is computing index 9  with value 89
    Process #1 is computing index 10  with value 90
    Process #1 is computing index 11  with value 91
  Process #2 startIdx=12  endIdx=17
    Process #2 is computing index 12  with value 92
    Process #2 is computing index 13  with value 93
    Process #2 is computing index 14  with value 94
    Process #2 is computing index 15  with value 95
    Process #2 is computing index 16  with value 96
    Process #2 is computing index 17  with value 97
  Process #3 startIdx=18  endIdx=23
    Process #3 is computing index 18  with value 98
    Process #3 is computing index 19  with value 99
    Process #3 is computing index 20  with value 100
    Process #3 is computing index 21  with value 101
    Process #3 is computing index 22  with value 102
  Process #4 startIdx=24  endIdx=29
    Process #3 is computing index 23  with value 103
    Process #4 is computing index 24  with value 104
    Process #4 is computing index 25  with value 105
    Process #4 is computing index 26  with value 106
    Process #4 is computing index 27  with value 107
    Process #4 is computing index 28  with value 108
    Process #4 is computing index 29  with value 109
  Process #5 startIdx=30  endIdx=35
    Process #5 is computing index 30  with value 110
    Process #5 is computing index 31  with value 111
    Process #5 is computing index 32  with value 112
    Process #5 is computing index 33  with value 113
    Process #5 is computing index 34  with value 114
    Process #5 is computing index 35  with value 115
  Process #6 startIdx=36  endIdx=41
    Process #6 is computing index 36  with value 116
    Process #6 is computing index 37  with value 117
    Process #6 is computing index 38  with value 118
  Process #7 startIdx=42  endIdx=50
    Process #6 is computing index 39  with value 119
    Process #6 is computing index 40  with value 120
    Process #7 is computing index 42  with value 122
    Process #6 is computing index 41  with value 121
    Process #7 is computing index 43  with value 123
    Process #7 is computing index 44  with value 124
    Process #7 is computing index 45  with value 125
    Process #7 is computing index 46  with value 126
    Process #7 is computing index 47  with value 127
    Process #7 is computing index 48  with value 128
    Process #7 is computing index 49  with value 129
    Process #7 is computing index 50  with value 130
* Finished
```

**It's worth to point out the obvious and say that each process knows what value is being processed at the moment, however, `main()` doesn't**.

`main()` just knows the index range that every process will work on but it doesn't know (in real-time) which values are currently being processed by those processes.

If you need `main()` to have access to this information while the processes are running it's probably best to setup a `Queue` in `main()` and run it on a separate `Thread` before the Pool starts. Then, make sure to send the `Queue` object as part of the parameters that are passed to every process so they can all share the same object and store the data they are processing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your code on modern multi-core CPU at a given point in time your worker processes will be executing in parallel several tasks. You can use a queue to implement a custom protocol that your workers will let main process know with, which task (index of task) they start and finish working on.

```
import os
import time
import queue
import random
import multiprocessing

def fn(st_queue, i):
    st_queue.put((multiprocessing.current_process().name, i))
    time.sleep(random.random())  # your long calculation
    st_queue.put((multiprocessing.current_process().name, None))
    return i ** 2

def main():
    status = {}
    st_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

    result = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    args = zip([st_queue] * 20, range(20))
    async_res = pool.starmap_async(
        fn, args, callback = lambda r: result.append(r))

    while not async_res.ready():
        try:
            msg = st_queue.get(True, 0.1)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            status.update([msg])
            print(status)      
    print(result.pop())
    pool.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Status dictionary looks like:

```
{
    'ForkPoolWorker-4': None, 
    'ForkPoolWorker-5': 16, 
    'ForkPoolWorker-2': 18, 
    'ForkPoolWorker-3': 15
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to report the index from the worker processes and you don't mind reporting them out of sequence, then you can use the enumeration approaches others have suggested. If you want to keep track of the work from the main process (e.g., to manage a status bar) and/or you need to know the total number of items that have been started, then you will need to have each worker report back to the parent as it starts. That can be done with a pipe as shown below.

I'm not sure whether you want to report the index of the item or the total number of items that have been started (they may start out of sequence), so I report both.

```
# dummy data and function
all_inputs = list(zip(range(10), range(20,30)))
def name_of_function(a, b):
    return a+b

# main code
from multiprocessing import Pool, Pipe, Lock

parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
lock = Lock()

def wrapper(idx, args):
    with lock:
        child_conn.send(idx)
    return name_of_function(*args)

with Pool(processes=5) as p:
    p.starmap_async(wrapper, enumerate(all_inputs))
    # receive status updates
    num_items = len(all_inputs)
    for i in range(num_items):
        idx = parent_conn.recv()
        print("processing index {} ({}/{})".format(idx, i+1, num_items))

child_conn.close()
parent_conn.close()

# output (note that items may be started out of sequence):
# processing index 0 (1/10)
# processing index 1 (2/10)
# processing index 2 (3/10)
# processing index 3 (4/10)
# processing index 5 (5/10)
# processing index 6 (6/10)
# processing index 4 (7/10)
# processing index 7 (8/10)
# processing index 8 (9/10)
# processing index 9 (10/10)
```

Note that this uses `starmap_async` instead of `starmap`, in order to continue execution of the main thread while the subprocesses run. Alternatively, you could use `starmap` and launch a separate thread to report progress, like this:

```
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Pool, Pipe, Lock
parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
lock = Lock()

def receive_updates(num_items):
    for i in range(num_items):
        idx = parent_conn.recv()
        print("processing index {} ({}/{})".format(idx, i+1, num_items))

def wrapper(idx, args):
    with lock:
        child_conn.send(idx)
    return name_of_function(*args)

# launch another thread to receive the results, since the main thread
# will wait for starmap
result_thread = Thread(target=receive_updates, args=(len(all_inputs),))
result_thread.Daemon = True  # stop if main thread is killed
result_thread.start()

# your original code
with Pool(processes=5) as p:
    p.starmap(wrapper, all_inputs)

child_conn.close()
parent_conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are content to know when each item is finished (instead of started), you could use `apply_async` with a callback, like this:

```
# dummy data and function
all_inputs = list(zip(range(10), range(20,30)))
def name_of_function(a, b):
    return a+b

# main code
from multiprocessing import Pool

num_items = len(all_inputs)
num_done = 0
def handle_result(res):
    global num_done
    num_done += 1
    print('finished item {} of {}.'.format(num_done, num_items))

p = Pool(5)
for args in all_inputs:
    p.apply_async(name_of_function, args, callback=handle_result)
p.close()
p.join() # wait for tasks to finish
```

result:

```
finished item 1 of 10.
finished item 2 of 10.
finished item 3 of 10.
finished item 4 of 10.
finished item 5 of 10.
finished item 6 of 10.
finished item 7 of 10.
finished item 8 of 10.
finished item 9 of 10.
finished item 10 of 10.
```

Note that results won't necessarily come in the same order as `all_inputs`. If you need to know exactly which item was processed, you could enumerate the arguments like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

num_items = len(all_inputs)
num_done = 0
def handle_result(idx):
    global num_done
    num_done += 1
    print('finished index {} ({}/{}).'.format(idx, num_done, num_items))

def wrapper(idx, args):
    name_of_function(*args)
    return idx

p = Pool(5)
for args in enumerate(all_inputs):
    p.apply_async(wrapper, args, callback=handle_result)
p.close()
p.join() # wait for tasks to finish
```

result:

```
finished index 0 (1/10).
finished index 1 (2/10).
finished index 2 (3/10).
finished index 3 (4/10).
finished index 4 (5/10).
finished index 6 (6/10).
finished index 8 (7/10).
finished index 7 (8/10).
finished index 9 (9/10).
finished index 5 (10/10).
```